# What happens in the end of the Tokyo Ravens anime?

Tags: tokyo-ravens

Harutora's attempt to resurrect Natsume supposedly succeeded, but Saotome Suzu, who had helped to perform the ritual, told the other characters over the phone that it *technically* was a success.

In the end, we see how Natsume is resting in a bed inside a brightly sunlit room with a window open. Harutora says he'll be looking forward to see her and disappears. It's not clear whether he was real or not, and whether the whole room is some metaphor of sorts, considering the "astrology" stuff in the previous episode.

What's really going on in the end of the anime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is still unclear in the anime. As of the time of writing, there are 11 volumes of light novel and the anime adaptation has covered up to volume 9 (titled *to The DarkSky*).

From [volume 9 chapter 5](http://www.baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=Tokyo_Ravens:Volume9_Chapter5) (emphasis mine):

> Was it a dream? She wasn't sure. Her fuzzy brain still wasn't working well. The sheets completely covered Natsume, and everything was unclear, so she couldn't make a normal judgment.
>
> Natsume softly touched her lips with her fingers. The sensation lingering there was inexplicably fresh, clear, and **real**. Natsume's face reddened and she buried her face in the covers again.

He is real. The incident did happen but we are not sure where. Resurrection was successful but there may other thing needed to be done for Natsume to live in real world.

The *technical* success Suzu was talking about is explained more clearly in [volume 10 chapter 3](http://www.baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=Tokyo_Ravens:Volume10_Chapter3):

> "Yes. I won't hide it any longer. My name is Tsuchimikado Natsume. I was adopted by the Tsuchimikado main family not long after birth and was raised as the next family head. Tsuchimikado Harutora is my childhood friend."

> "Also...... It's true that I'm a dead person. Last summer, I was resurrected from death. ......No, I was just awakened, and right now I'm still barely maintaining my current state."

In the future, there may be an OVA for the remaining part of LN which may go into detail on it.

Answer (score 1):

What I personally think has happened... Since Harutora has now full control of the raven cape and also knows that Kon has transformed into Hishamaru, and when she did transform into her, Harutora knew her name. This shows that he regained his memories of being Yakou.

As Yakou was a genius omnyoji and visionary, he was able to create the ritual of Taizan Fukun. He was able to reincarnate himself into Harutora, this is proven in the premise of the first paragraph. We can then conclude that when Harutora was in the white room with Natsume and he said "I hope to see you again", in addition to Suzu Saotome's response of the ritual being "technically successful", we can infer that Natsume will be reincarnated. Since Harutora's memories of Yakou developed so have his skills and memories of his own Taizan Fukun ritual. Yakou is the only person capable of performing this ritual, and it succeeds. The last season of episode 24 was Harutora and his shikigami's walking away from the ritual after it has succeeded. Harutora will meet Natsume again, her reincarnation that is.

*Just a theory*. I really enjoyed this series and I hope to see a second season, with proof of my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

According to the light novel, Natsume is revived through the ritual but there was a problem - she had to be fused with her dragon, Hokuto, or else she will die. Her current situation is just like Toji (half ogre). The onmoyo agency declared Harutora as a most wanted criminal & he also acts like one. Harutora suffers from memory conflicts from both his lives. Sometimes it's Harutora dominant & he cares about Natsume & others, while most of time its Yakou dominant......

I can't wait for season 2.... Hope they release it soon...

Answer (score 0):

As of now more has been translated for us since to work with. Because of that I had to disagree on  Senshin's statement that Harutora had to sacrifice something to save her.

Because from what I read and how I understood it the ritual was a success. But it was not the exact results they were trying for.

Remember it was pointed out that the name of the ritual is actually the system the ritual is based off of. It was also pointed out that there are many different things this system is capable of.

We also know that Suzuka was forced to study the ritual further to either verify what all was known about it or to try and learn more about it. I'm leaning more towards the possibility that it was both.

Either way we now know for sure that not everything is known about this ritual. Soi would say when he revived Natsume he did the same thing the omniyo agency did when they performed it. Which means he revived her as a familiar. But she doesn't have a master thus making her a rogue familiar and not a living spirit like it is explained.

Now before anyone says she is one and they say she is in the story let's remember a few things. Hokuto was a familiar. Hokuto was used to bind Natsume's spirit. Logically that would mean Natsume is now a familiar.

Following this vein of thought I have the belief that because she is a familiar without a master her spirit is unstable and will be until she A. dies B.gets a master or C. Harutora finds a way to separate hokuto from Natsume's without destroying the bond that is keeping her alive.

That is what I came up with to explain how the ritual could "kinda work" when Natsume is now alive but having trouble staying stable enough to live.

Comment: FYI, I haven't commented on or answered this question - you probably mean some other user said that "Harutora had to sacrifice something to save her"

Answer (score -2):

I think a hint was shown in the blonde-haired girl's star reading (I forgot her name). Being that there are many universes.... What if Harutora had to sacrifice his place in the current universe he is in (so he sacrificed his place in the world for Natsume)? So to sum that up, the ritual "kind of" worked as Natsume has been placed into the universe she left, but Harutora sacrificed his position. Also, when she got kissed it was somewhat real? Like, being Yakou, he managed to travel to her universe for a period of time. When you see him walk off with his familiars he is in another universe. When he says "I hope to see you again" I'm guessing he meant "hope to see you again in another universe," like see her other self in another universe.

I have no idea where this popped out from but this is my theory.

Comment: You should not post questions in your answer. An answer answers a question, not asking another questions. You can comment on existing answers or question after earning 20 reputation points.

Answer (score -3):

Well, it seems like Natsume has been reincarnated, but for some reason, Harutora had to leave her behind, right? The obvious answer is, he did something taboo, forbidden, and there seems to be some unfinished business with the Taizan Fukun ritual, which makes it logical that he make his escape so that he could finish what he started.

Also, it seems logical for Natsume to be left behind like that...I mean if you think about it, Harutora must have sacrificed something bigger than life to dabble on something as taboo as resurrecting the dead--which in any other anime I've seen--is more seriously labeled as evil magic.

Given Natsume's character, she wouldn't have allowed Harutora to do something like that--in fact, she had already voiced her objections back when Suzuka attempted to use the same ritual. This reason alone puts Harutora in a precarious situation where he must resurrect Natsume against her consent. Her objecting to the process might only complicate things and distract him from his--should we call it romantic or obsessive--goal of prolonging her life or resurrecting her completely as a normal human being.

If I were Harutora, it would be too frightening to face someone you love only to tell her that her life depends on certain `uncertainties' including the help of other-worldly gods, demons, or what-have-you and doing all that for what reason? For love that is pure and true? I don't think Harutora even has the slightest understanding of what he truly feels for Natsume, though the fact that he does feel something profoundly and frighteningly deep is itself beyond doubt...

Having said that, I'd probably put on my best sneakers and prepare to run, if only to save myself from the embarrassingly disturbing explanations--and confessions--I'd have to make to satisfy Natsume's excruciatingly probing curiosity..

Finally, if Harutora had to sacrifice himself eventually, as that could be the only possibility left to complete the ritual, I'm sure he wouldn't want to do it right in front of her. He knew what that felt like, having witnessed Natsume's death first-hand, and being the cause of it too. I think he wouldn't hesitate to give up everything for her, but just so he didn't have to feel so bad about it, he could do that on his own, like some supreme, heroic sacrifice that nobody should interfere with, especially Natsume, who might reject that offering--a rejection that to Harutora would be even more tragic because as is surprisingly obvious, he's just that kind of guy who doesn't know when to give up. Or maybe it's just the case of stubborn true love?

What's clear is that he is unwilling to go on with his own existence without Natsume, as is obvious when he touched the missing pentagram on his upper left cheek right after the death incident and mourned her loss crying out her name repeatedly--something he was only able to do when he was imprisoned by Kurahashi/Yashimaru in the Onmyou Agency headquarters.

The feeling that somebody has to die somewhere down the road towards Natsume's final resurrection depresses me as this seems ominous from the very start... That Harutora might have to figuratively die to give way to Yakou's complete awakening as a means to perfecting the forbidden ritual is a strong possibility, then there's the more poignant possibility of Natsume giving up her life to free Harutora from the obligation he had set upon himself to resurrect her, especially when she realizes eventually the depth of his sacrifice... I don't know which way the story might go, but there's bound to be something romantically tragic in the end... and it almost makes me reluctant to know how everything might really turn out... huh, talk about 50 shades of reincarnation, right?

Comment: I strongly suggest you go over your answer and review just to check if the paragraph breaks i made made sense not to mention i do not know what the purpose of the `--` in some sentences are

Comment: I can only see the first 2 paragraph answering the question `What's really going on in the end?` The rest derails into an analysis of Harutora's action.